# Looking for a (S)FTP Server on Linux, on which users can create easily accounts for sharing

Tags: linux, ftp, linux-distribution, sftp

As an IT department we would like to provide to our business (not tech persons) a possiblity to let them create easily (S)FTP accounts by their own for sharing data with external users.

The (S)FTP Server solution should be run on `Linux`.

It would be very helpful, if the (S)FTP Server solution would have layers like this:

- **Admin layer:** In this layer, the IT deparment should have access have full rights over each (S)FTP account. IT should be able to set some storage quoata for set of users/roles.
- **Admin light layer:** In this layerour employees from the business should have the possiblity to create and manage (S)FTP Accounts for sharing with their project partners
- **User layer:** in this layerexternal users (project partners) should have access to the data, which was shared for themself.

It would be nice, if it could be managed, that the sign in into the (S)FTP Server solution for internal users (**Admin layer** and **Admin light layer**) with their `Active Directory` credentials. This would make the administration for the IT deparment simple.

Is there any solution that you could recommend? Thank you.

Comment: Does this *needs* to be SFTP? There are already a few file sharing servers with those function, but that operate on though a web interface instead of the normal FTP protocol.

Comment: @Alejandro well, im open to new solutions. it doesn't have to be explicitly (S)FTP. but what it's required is that the service/data has to be on-prem (not in a cloud) running on linux and also be able to share data >1'000GB without any issues.

Comment: @Alejandro Anything you would recommend to me? Thank you.